# Converting a non-parametrized list to a parametrized one in java

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, thrift

I have a method that returns a generic `List`. It can either be `List<Map>` or `List<List>` depending on the way the method executes.

```
//sendthis can be either be List<Map> or List<List>
List sendthis = myClass.myMethod();
```

I'm using Apache thrift to send this `List` from the server to the client(python). I need the list to be a `List<Map>` at the client side. Thrift doesn't allow heterogeneous collections so I need to convert the list `sendthis` to a `List<Map>`.

In my case `myMethod()` returns the `List` only as a `List<Map>` but I cannot send it using thrift because thrift expects a `List<Map>` and not a `List`.

Is there any way to convert `sendthis` to a `List<Map>` without iterating over the original list and copying to a new one, as the list can contain tens of thousands of entries.

**NOTE**

I tried simply casting it to the required type but with no success.

**EDIT**

`myMethod()`'s definition cannot be changed.

Comment: why do you say casting did not work?

Comment: What do you mean by the last statement 'I tried simply casting it to the required type but with no success'? does it fail during at runtime or what?

Comment: Basically, your API accepts List<Map> but it may be, that your code produces a List<List>? That is not convertible "at default", as List and Map are different data structures and how do you decide which kind of data structure is inside your list after receiving it at the client?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, @ankur: casting it does not produce any error in the java server but it cannot be passed through thrift to the client. I cannot read the list in the client unless i send exactly a `List<Map>`

Comment: @Smutje: I can control what list the method produces, and i have set it to produce a list<map> and it does (checked by sysout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thrift doesn't allow heterogeneous collections

Yes and no.

```
union Whatever {
  1 :  Foo foo
  2 :  Bar bar
}

type list<Whatever>  HeterogeneousList
```

Now you have a list which can hold `Foo`s along with `Bar`s. How cool is that?

Comment: This means I need to have `Whatever` in my java side as well?

Answer (score 1):

Since all classes in java extend `java.lang.Object` you can simply define the list like this:

```
List<? extends Object>
```

Comment: Map is not a Collection.

Comment: Map interface does not extend Collection.

Comment: that's true. what was i thinking... thanks for the hint!

Comment: My problem is not in the java side, I can read it just fine but the problem is when I pass it to thrift. Thrift IDLs support only list set and map.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can always poll your list and check its first argument to determine the true nature of the list. Since you are working with raw types, you will have no remedy but to get some warnings suppressed (once you are sure of what you are doing).

This is an idea of how it could work:

```
List<?> unknown = getUnknowList();
if(!unknown.isEmpty()){
    Object first = unknown.get(0);
    if(first instanceof List){

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<List<?>> data = (List<List<?>>) unknown;
        doWhatYouWannaDoWithLists(data);

    } else if(first instanceof Map){

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Map<?,?>> data = (List<Map<?,?>>) unknown;
        doWhatYouWannaDoWithMaps(data);

    }
}
```